# Does AWS Lambda supports PHP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am just a beginner to AWS. I need to know about lambda support. I am working on PHP.
Is the lambda supports PHP? If not is there any other alternative solution for it which supports PHP?

Comment: Still nothing. In the meantime, I know its a stretch but, vote for php being added to lambda natively here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=845520&#845520

Answer (score 4):

Actually no, but since November of 2018 AWS announced the Lambda layer which is basically the way to you run your own runtime such as PHP. You have two simple ways to run lambda with PHP

1 - Create your own cloudformation stack passing the PHP layer for example `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:887080169480:layer:php73:2`

Something like that
template.yml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: ''

Resources:
    MyFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            FunctionName: 'php-layer'
            Description: ''
            CodeUri: .
            Handler: index.php
            Timeout: 10 # Timeout in seconds
            MemorySize: 1024 # The memory size is related to the pricing and CPU power
            Runtime: provided
            Layers:
                - 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:887080169480:layer:php73:2'
```

And create a PHP file
index.php

```
<?php
echo "Hello from PHP Experience 2019";
?>
```

Create an AWS s3 bucket (for example mybuckettest)

Packaged cloudformation stack

```
sam package \
    --template-file template.yml \
    --output-template-file serverless-output.yaml \
    --s3-bucket phpex
```

Deploy your stack

```
sam deploy \
    --template-file serverless-output.yaml \
    --stack-name php-layer \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

done

2 - Use the [bref.sh](https://bref.sh) a very simple PHP framework for aws lambda

Answer (score 2):

Natively AWS Lambda supports only following languages as of May 22, 2017

1. C#
2. Edge Node.js 4.3
3. Java 8
4. Node,js 4.3
5. Node.js 6.10
6. Python 2.7
7. Python 3.6

However if you want, you can tweak it a bit to use PHP as outlined [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes AWS Lambda does support PHP with a little tweaking. Here are a couple links to get you started.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-lambda.html

Comment: I don't know if I should upvote. On one hand - it is an answer. On other: wtf!? why AWS does not support php as it deserve to!? :-( This approach with Node.js wrapper pushes us to better learn Python or Node.js than to wrap and what about composer dependecies and other php practices? :-(

Comment: I agree with @Alex.  I would not call it "support", but "workaround". Is it a valid answer: partially, since the question also was for ANY alternative solution

Comment: Here is another solurtion : https://github.com/mnapoli/bref . It is still wrap the php, but automates a lot of AWS with cloud foundation commands

Answer (score 1):

As from the latest update!!, AWS Almbda Does Support PHP now.

Source : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/

Comment: Also this os quite helpful: https://medium.com/@stephenheron/serverless-php-9da3f00df5de

Comment: At reInvent 2018 AWS announced support for custom runtimes via Layers. PHP is being lead by stackery. ARN for PHP here: https://github.com/stackery/php-lambda-layer

Comment: @antonioortegajr Re-Invent happens in December 2018 and i have shared my findings before that. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: This tutorial starts with `In the Amazon EC2 console, choose Launch instance.` Shouldn't it be serverless?

Answer (score 0):

When you work with AWS Lambda, you may also want to work with [serverless](https://serverless.com/) package as it  makes ongoing deployment and code management easier.
you can check my implementation of [serverless-php-lambda](https://github.com/niron1/serverless-php-lambda) based on running amazon-linux vm and getting all php binaries from there. this allows to configure php more easier, no compilation, with libraries such as redis etc.